# How Can put lateral title in block Tikz Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

Hi Have the following code and I would like to set the title on the left, so that on the right I will be able to load an Image

```
  \documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
%\geometry{paperwidth=1080px,paperheight=1980px}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use columns:

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}


\begin{columns}
\column{0.5} 
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}

\column{0.5} \node at (9.5cm,21cm) {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]